# How do I contact Facebook

Tags: facebook

Contacting Facebook can prove to be challenge for some, are there any emails or phone numbers that are active for Facebook?

I know that some of the email addresses come from replies to Facebook others from Support forms.

The rest of the list I think will be made up of Facebook employee usernames e.g. zuck@fb.com

Is there a list out there that contains this?

So far I have found http://www.marismith.com/how-contact-facebook-directory-of-forms/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of emails that have been passed out over the years

- privacy@facebook.com (inactive?)
- login@facebook.com (inactive?)
- info@facebook.com (inactive?)
- disabled@facebook.com (inactive?)
- abuse@facebook.com (inactive?)
- appeals@facebook.com (inactive?)

Phone numbers from a Google Maps search

- (650) 853-1300 (inactive?)
- (408) 844-4043 (marketing) (inactive?)

Press

- press@fb.com

Facebook Groups

- https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

IRC

- #facebook irc.freenode